# Uniqueness of Invertible Sheaf on Normal Surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Assume $S$ is a ***normal*** surface (so 2-dimensional $k$-scheme). Let $\mathcal{L}, \mathcal{N}$ be zwo invertible sheaves on $S$ such that they coinside on a dense open subset $U \subset S$; so $\mathcal{L} \vert_U= \mathcal{N} \vert _U$.

Why does this already imply that $\mathcal{L}=\mathcal{N}$on whole $S$?

My considerations: Since $\mathcal{L} \otimes \mathcal{N}^{\vee}$ is also invertible and therefore wlog $\mathcal{L}= O_S$.

Assume that $\mathcal{N} \vert_U= O_U$. How does this equality extend to whole $S$?

My ideas: for every $U \subset V$ we have diagram

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
O_S(V) @>{a_V???}  >> \mathcal{N} \vert_V \\
@VVcanV  @VVcanV  \\
O_S(U) @>{\cong}>> \mathcal{N} \vert_U;
\end{CD}
$$

and we want that this diagram extends to $a_V$ and futhermore it is an isomorphism. From here I'm stuck. How to use here the normality condition to obtain the desired result?

Comment: Any such $N$ is isomorphic to the trivial bundle on a suitable dense open set, so unless you put restrictions on $U$, this will not be true.

Comment: Are you sure this is true? What about $\mathbb{P}^2$ and $\mathcal{O}$ and $\mathcal{O}(1)$? They are isomorphic over $U=\mathbb{A}^2$. I think you need complement of $U$ to have  codimension $2$. This may be what you are thinking of: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1258398/extending-regular-function-on-normal-variety-from-a-subvariety-of-codimension-2