# Is a morphism from a quasi-affine variety to a quasi-projective variety given by globally defined regular maps?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space, ringed-spaces, classical-algebraic-geometry

$\def\bbA{\mathbb{A}}
\def\bbP{\mathbb{P}}
\def\sO_{\mathcal{O}}$The following discussion is strictly classical. Throughout this question, I will use the notions of (i) sheaf of $k$-algebras, (ii) $k$-ringed space and (iii) morphism of $k$-ringed spaces as they are defined in [Milne's book](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/AG.pdf), Chapter 3, sections a, b, d. These are not the same definitions as for general ringed spaces (they are what Görtz and Wedhorn—in the first chapter of their AlgGeom book—call a *space with functions* and a *morphism of spaces with functions*). In particular, one has

> **Lemma.** “Being a morphism” is a property of maps between $k$-ringed spaces that is locally on the target. Explicitly, let $(X,\sO_X),(Y,\sO_Y)$ be $k$-ringed spaces and let $\varphi:X\to Y$ be a function. The following are equivalent:
>
> 1. $\varphi$ is a morphism of $k$-ringed spaces,
> 2. for all open sets $V\subset Y$, the map $\varphi|_{\varphi^{-1}(V)}:\varphi^{-1}(V)\to V$ is a morphism, and
> 3. there is an open cover $Y=\bigcup_iV_i$ of $Y$ such that $\varphi|_{\varphi^{-1}(V_i)}:\varphi^{-1}(V_i)\to V$ is a morphism for all $i$.

I will set up notations. Let $k$ be an arbitrary field. The $n$-dimensional affine space $\bbA_k^n=k^n$ and projective space $\bbP_k^n=\bbA_k^{n+1}/k^*$ are topological spaces where the closed sets are the vanishing sets of polynomials (homogeneous on the latter case), the "Zariski topology."

By definition, a (quasi-)affine (resp., a (quasi-)projective) variety is a locally ringed space that is isomorphic to a Zariski (locally) closed subset of $\bbA_k^n$ (resp., of $\bbP_k^n$) equipped with the sheaf of $k$-algebras of regular functions. These are the functions that are locally written as a quotient of polynomials (with non-vanishing denominator) required to be homogeneous of same degree in the projective case.

If $X$ and $Y$ are both quasi-affine varieties, both quasi-projective varieties or one of them quasi-affine and the other one quasi-projective, by definition a regular map $X\to Y$ is a morphism of $k$-ringed spaces $(X,\sO_X)\to (Y,\sO_Y)$. Thus, quasi-affine + quasi-projective varieties and the regular maps assemble into a category.

From this definition, it can be proven that

1. If $X,Y$ are quasi-affine varieties, with $Y\subset\bbA_k^m$, then a map $\varphi=(\varphi_1,\dots,\varphi_m):X\to Y$ (where $\varphi_i=y_i\circ\varphi$) is regular if and only if $\varphi_i\in\Gamma(X,\sO_X)$ for all $i$.
2. For $0\leq i\leq n$, the map
   \begin{align*}
   \bbA_k^n&\longrightarrow U_i=\bbP_k^n\setminus V(x_i)\\
           (a_1,\dots,a_n)&\longmapsto (a_1:\dots:a_{i-1}:1:a_i:\cdots:a_n)
   \end{align*}
   is an isomorphism.

Here is my problem: I am trying to characterize the regular maps that go from a quasi-affine variety into a quasi-projective variety. Using the two last facts and the lemma, one can show

> **Proposition.** Let $X\subset\bbA_k^n$ be quasi-affine, $Y\subset\bbP_k^m$ be quasi-projective and $\varphi:X\to Y$ be a map. Then $\varphi$ is regular if and only if each point of $X$ has an open neighborhood $U$ on which there are defined regular functions $f_0,\dots,f_m\in \sO_X(U)$ with
> $$
> \varphi(a_1,\dots,a_n)=(f_0(a_1,\dots,a_n):\dots:f_m(a_1,\dots,a_n))
> $$
> for all $(a_1,\dots,a_n)\in U$.

Now, what I am trying to prove or disprove is the following

> **Conjecture.** Let $X\subset\bbA_k^n$ be quasi-affine, $Y\subset\bbP_k^m$ be quasi-projective and $\varphi:X\to Y$ be a map. Then $\varphi$ is regular if and only if there are globally-defined regular functions $f_0,\dots,f_m\in \Gamma(X,\sO_X)$ with
> $$
> \varphi(a_1,\dots,a_n)=(f_0(a_1,\dots,a_n):\dots:f_m(a_1,\dots,a_n))
> $$
> for all $(a_1,\dots,a_n)\in X$.

I want to say in advance that I deem this conjecture to be false, by what Milne writes in section 6.l of his book. However, I don't know any counterexamples, so I would be grateful if someone could indicate some.

Comment: Please don't change the question after an answer has been provided. Questions should not be a moving target.

Comment: @KReiser I guess you are right. I just changed it back to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood your question, take $Y=\{xy-zw=0\}\subset \mathbb{A}^4$ and $X=Y-\{0,0,0,0\}$. Then you have a morphism $ X\to\mathbb{P}^1$ given by $(x,z)$ on points where at least one of them do not vanish and where they both vanish, given by $(w,y)$. You can check that this is an example of what you seek.

I am adding a few more details. You have a morphism from $Y\to \mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1\subset \mathbb{P}^3$, since $\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1$ is given by the same equation, $xy-zw=0$ in $\mathbb{P}^3$. The map I described above is just the map from $X\to\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1$ composed with one of the projections to $\mathbb{P}^1$.

If this map can be defined by two regular functions $f,g\in \Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)=\Gamma(Y,\mathcal{O}_Y)=k[x,yz,w]/(xy-zw)=R$, one first checks that $f,g$ are homogeneous of the same positive degree. Since the map is defined on $X$, one sees that the only common zero of $f,g$ in $Y$ is just the origin. This says that the height of the ideal $(f,g)\subset R$ must be the height of the maximal ideal, which is three. But, Krull's principal ideal theorem says that this height can be at most two, a contradiction.

Comment: I am trying to derive a contradiction from assuming the existence of globally defined regular maps $f_0,f_1\in\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ such that $X\to\mathbb{P}_k^1$ is given by $a=(x,y,z,w)\in X\mapsto(f_0(a):f_1(a))$. But I don't see why this cannot be the case. Could you hint at some details on this last part?

Comment: @ElíasGuisadoVillalgordo I have added some more details.

Comment: I am sorry to answer so late, I was in a break of math. I wanted to ask you: from the facts you point out, why does it follow that the height of the ideal $(f,g)$ must be the height of the maximal ideal? Thank you.

Comment: Also: Is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1258398/394668) the justification for $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)=\Gamma(Y,\mathcal{O}_Y)$? If that is the case, how do we know that $R$ is normal?